# Does "to" correspond to verb inflection in X-bar theory?

Tags: inflection, x-bar-theory, infinitive

In this Government & Binding Theory book I'm reading, it is *assumed* that "to" in to-infinitives corresponds to *verb inflection*, meaning that in x-bar tree "to" appears under INFL, exactly where one puts "tense" markers (i.e. the suffix -ed).

What I don't quite follow in this *assumption* is that "to" is not a suffix and it is not a tense, so I fail to see why it would be associated with "verb inflection" in x-bar theory. Then again, if you don't put "to" under INFL, where would you put it? But is that sufficient grounds for saying that "to" *corresponds* to "verb inflection"?

Now, this particular book dates back to 1991, and I wonder if its assumption/view still holds today, or if it has been modified/discarded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have read of an analysis where "to" is analyzed as an auxiliary. That sounds similar (in G&B, auxiliaries are associated with INF, right?).

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense, “to” is simply a particle.

Comment: @Atamiri: How does calling something "simply a particle" explain how it functions grammatically?

Comment: Nothing to do with inflection. "To" is a subordinator, a special marker  for VPs of infinitival clauses.